# HttpClient PostAsync on xamarin does nothing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a piece of code

```
var formContent =
    new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", _userName),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", _password)
    });

var response = await InternalClient.PostAsync("/Token", formContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It works fine when i use it in my desktop app, but this very same piece fails on Xamarin.Android. I can access my web site from emulators browser, so it's not the case of not having the connection between these two. Even more interesting part - GetAsync works absolutely fine. PostAsync always fails with TaskCancelledException because of timeout. All the PostAsync calls do not hit the server at all.
My activity where this is executed:

```
var isAuthSuccess = _mainClient.Authenticate();

isAuthSuccess.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        if (isAuthSuccess.Result)
        {
            ReleaseEventHandlers();

            var nav = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
            nav.NavigateTo("MainChatWindow", _mainClient);
        }

        button.Enabled = true;
    });
});
```

And the Authenticate method:

```
public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
{
    var getTokenOperation = new AsyncNetworkOperation<string>(GetTokenOperation);
    var token = await getTokenOperation.Execute().ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (getTokenOperation.IsCriticalFailure)
    {
        SetCriticalFailure(getTokenOperation.FailureReason);
    }

    if (getTokenOperation.IsFailure == false)
    {
        InternalClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        AuthenticationFailEncounteredEvent("Authentication fail encountered: " + getTokenOperation.FailureReason);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Get token operation:

```
private async Task<string> GetTokenOperation()
{
    var formContent =
            new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", _userName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", _password)
            });

    var response = await InternalClient.PostAsync("/Token", formContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeVerbose();

    var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
    var token = jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();

    return token;
}
```

And the wrapper - AsyncNetworkOperation

```
public class AsyncNetworkOperation<T>
{
    public bool IsFailure { get; set; }

    public bool IsCriticalFailure { get; set; }

    public string FailureReason { get; set; }

    public bool IsRepeatable { get; set; }

    public int RepeatsCount { get; set; }

    public Func<Task<T>> Method { get; set; }

    public AsyncNetworkOperation(Func<Task<T>> method, int repeatsCount)
    {
        Method = method;
        IsRepeatable = true;
        RepeatsCount = repeatsCount;
    }

    public AsyncNetworkOperation(Func<Task<T>> method)
    {
        Method = method;
    }

    public async Task<T> Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            return await Method().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        ...exception handling logics
    }
}
```

Calling PostAsync right in the activity behaves the same - waits for quite a long time and then fails with TaskCancelledException because of timeout.

Comment: 1) What exactly do you mean by "fails"? 2) Are there any differences in the cal stack for this method?

Comment: by fails i mean that it throws an exception and never actually hits the server. Didn't check the call stack diff - it's just within the same class library which I'm using for desktop and android versions.

Comment: added more source code so the picture is more accurate now

Comment: @HardLuck Does `InternalClient` have a timeout set or anything like that? Maybe I would try removing all of the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` code to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Nope, it has no such settings, I've tried remove ConfigureAwait, same result. Emphasizing 2 things: it works good on doesktop, on Xamarin calling just PostAsync from activity (not from library) fails as well. GetAsync works everywhere

Comment: @HardLuck: Have you [granted appropriate permissions to your mobile app](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/)?

Comment: My app has ALL possible permissions available in manifest

Comment: @HardLuck Might be a long shot but have you tried running it on a different device?

Comment: Unfortunately i have only emulators at my disposal

Comment: In my case I had set the Authorization header to empty string which was causing this issue, after removing the headers and trimming all the key value pairs in POST key value pairs it worked fine. Unfortunately no errors were thrown to explain this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the struggling with the same issue - this is related to SSL (self signed cert in my case). If you are trying to connect to your server via HTTPS - try using plain HTTP first, my app can work with HTTP fine while HTTPS hangs to death.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. For allowing self-signed certs in service calls, I would suggest adding the following to your MainActivity (or anywhere really) which will allow the certs (also noting the DEBUG statements so it does not make it into production): `#if DEBUG System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslError) => return true; #endif`

Comment: that's where a possible bug might be, no matter where I add this event handler (library\activity\etc) it's always ignored for untrusted certs.

Comment: Yea I have had lots of problems with self-signed certs on Android and even more on iOS. You may try installing the self-signed cert into the device/emulator... or just stop using HTTP as you said, which might be the easier route to take

Answer (score 0):

I have had other problems with `PostAsync()` also and it is also not as customizable as `SendAsync()` in terms of editing the headers and things like that. I would recommend `SendAsync()`:

```
HttpRequestMessage  request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/Token") { Content = formContent };
HttpResponseMessage message = await InternalClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Unfortuantely SendAsync with `HttpMethod.Post` behaves the same

Comment: @HardLuck Then it must be an issue somewhere else because it works fine for me. Maybe post more code to see what the issue might be.

Comment: added more source code so the picture is more accurate now